# How can i craft a new mysql database instance based on a mysqldump from another host

Tags: mysql

Here is the scenario:

I have a brand new database, with the tables with NO data. Just bare minimum like usernames / passwords , etc.

I also have a mysqldump of a database with fully populated data.
now:

1. Can i export the fully populated database to a cvs / text file
2. Control the number of items in certain tables
3. Restore the changed / crafted database to mysql as a database instance

Comment: Are the table schemas the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump as CSV

```
mysqldump -pPASSWORD -u USER -T DIRECTORY --fields-terminated-by=, DATABASE
```

PARTIAL DUMP

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE TABLE_NAME -w"CONDITION_LIKE_WHERE_USER_NAME>100" > fileName.sql
```

RESTORE FROM DUMP

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < DUMPFILE
```

**refer:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html